# How to Display the Data have more than two spaces in Repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, repeater

I got the data from database into my dataset is [image] and then i bind into my repeater control but its is been showing like "Prince Antony G". It eliminated the Spaces.
and also i export those data into excel, In excel also the spaces were removed.
I need the show data whatever in my Database. Any idea to solve this problem.

**In stack overflow Question box also remove more spaces in between two words**

My Excel Coding:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Report");
    DataRow dr;
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");   

    for (int i = 0; i < dt_Status.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr["Name"] ="<pre>"+ dt_Status.Rows[i]["NAME"].ToString() +"</pre>";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

    // first let's clean up the response.object
    response.Clear();
    response.Charset = "";

    // set the response mime type for excel
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.xls");

    // create a string writer
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            // instantiate a datagrid
            DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
            dg.DataSource = dt;
            dg.DataBind();
            dg.RenderControl(htw);
            response.Write(sw.ToString());
            response.End();
        }
    }
```

After updating my code i got the excel output as:

[image]

I need to display in a single cell.

Comment: @Star:Why you remove the last line?

Comment: i didn't. you can see older versions of you Q when you edit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html doesn't recognize multiple spaces.

You you put your data between `<pre></pre>` tags to say that is is per-formatted.

Or you could replace the space with `&nbsp;`. This is a [non breaking space character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

Space is used for formatting your html code, and hence if you have more than one space, it gets wrapped to just one.

Comment: <pre> tag be one of the solution to bind in repeater control. Thanks .. But for excel what shall do?

Comment: To write to excel, use the values fetched from the database.

Comment: yeah i fetched directly from database

Comment: Can you post your excel writing code? If you are writing values from the db, there should not be a problem

Comment: i have Posted my coding here.. just check it.

Comment: You are using `RenderControl` to write the excel. This will only use the html output of your DataGrid. So once the output rendered by the Grid is fixed by the above solution, this will be solved too

Comment: Hai i have one problem.. while export the data into excel it is been taken two cell as a one cell. how to display it into a single cell

Answer (score 0):

A simple handy stuff:

```
string value = String.Join(" ", "Prince Antony G".Split(new char[] {' '}, 
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```